# How do I break down the math symbols in this equation

Tags: notation

> $$\frac{n}{\phi(n)}=\frac{n}{n\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)}=\frac{1}{\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)}$$

How do I learn to understand these equations by myself as I can't seem to find the mathematical notation descriptions online?

Comment: The $\phi(n)$ refers to [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). As explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler's_product_formula), the $\prod_{p\mid n}$ refers to taking a product over all distinct primes $p$ that divide $n$.

Comment: For symbols you don't know, you can get help from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The big pi, $\prod$ denotes a *product*. The subscript on this tells you which numbers this product is over. In this example, the subscript says $p|n$ which means "$p$ divides $n$" i.e. the product is over all the prime numbers $p$ that divide $n$ (the prime factors of $n$). $\phi(n)$ denotes [the Euler-Totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). This counts the number of integers $m<n$ which are co-prime to $n$, i.e. have $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

As an example, say we have $n=105=3\times5\times7$. Then $$\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac1p\right)=\left(1-\frac13\right)\times\left(1-\frac15\right)\times\left(1-\frac17\right)=\frac{16}{35}$$